# MySQL - Copy data from one table into another in a random order

Tags: mysql, random, sql-order-by, insert-into

I have created a new table identical to the original one and I would like to copy all the data to the new table in a random way.

I use:

```
INSERT INTO `new_table` (`id`, `value`) 
    SELECT `id`, `value` FROM `original_table` ORDER BY RAND();
```

But as result I get new table in the same order as original one. For some reason RAND() is not working.

**SOLVED**

Sorry, that was my fault. Thank you for hinting comments, that helped. Since I have found threads asking similar quesiton I leave this post up. So I was trying to mix rows to make a dynamic content slider with those data a bit more interesting and I actually was needed to mix the IDs, so I just was supposed to take id columnt out of the query:

```
INSERT INTO `new_table` (`value`) 
    SELECT `value` FROM `original_table` ORDER BY RAND();
```

Comment: Id and value are strings

Comment: What do you mean by "random order"? How do you determine the order?

Comment: @NicoHaase If I bluntly SELECT from the new table with no condtions I get the result rows in the same order as the original result

Comment: Rows in relational database tables have no order, so the question is meaningless